# how to run a local node js server only when starting desktop electron app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, electron, desktop

I want my node js server to run when my electron app is open.

I have tried the child_process module to run a shell command like this:

```
const {exec} = require('child_process')

const startDBServer = exec('node ./express.js');

startDBServer.stdout.on('data', (pid)=>{
    console.log(pid);
});

startDBServer.stderr.on('data', (data)=>{
    console.error(data);
});
```

the serve is running on port 8000 but it doesn't connect to the database (when the database connect it should print "mongoose connected" on the console but it just print "App started with port 8000" with no database connection).
this is my server

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const cors = require('cors');

const path = require('path')

mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/myDb')
.then(()=>{
    console.log('mongoose connected')
})
.catch((err)=> console.log('error is '+ err))


app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/views'))


app.use(cors({
    origin: '*'
}));

/* All middlewares */
require('./middlewares/app.middlewares')(app, express);

/* All the routes */
require('./router/index')(app);


/* starting the app */
app.listen(8000, ()=>{
    console.log('App started with port 8000')
})
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't connect to the database"? Is there any error or other log?

Comment: @MikeSzyndel in my express server when the database connect it should print "mongoose connected" on the console but it just print "App started with port 8000" with no database connection

Comment: Does it log an error then? You may have to wait a while there's probably a 30 second timeout for connection errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//mongoose does not work with name : localhost but with the address instead

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/myDb')
.then(()=>{
    console.log('mongoose connected')
})
.catch((err)=> console.log('error is '+ err))
```

Comment: it worked! thank you so much. but why it was working outside of electron main.js file? like when i use the "node myServer" command directly from the cmd the database connect successfully